# how to arrange the text one after the another with for each in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show some "ingredients" for my menus, but instead of showing them one after another, they are shown vertically. This is a picture how it looks like -> [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWIaY.png) and this is how I want to look [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr8VF.png)

I'll show the code bellow :

```
  VStack  {
        ForEach(meniu!.ingredients) { men in
            let ingredient = syncViewModel.fetchByIdIngredients(ingredientId: men.ingredient)
            if ingredient != nil {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(ingredient?.name ?? ""), ")
                        .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                }
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `VStack` with `HStack` ? Note, there is probably no need for the `EmptyView()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `VStack` at the top with an `HStack`.

You are now creating one `HStack` for each ingredient, but they are all joined together by the stack around the `ForEach`.

I propose the following solution to avoid weird behaviours:

```
struct MyRecipe: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe(ingredients: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]))      // Use your code instead of this example array
    }
    
    func recipe(ingredients: [String]) -> String {
        return ingredients.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i have something like this.. https://imgur.com/FMNOU74

Comment: The strange view is because SwiftUI is stacking all the ingredients horizontally. To solve you problem, I suggest to create a `func` that joins the Strings together, then display the result as a Text(String).