# How to arrange text horizontaly in a for each in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to arrange a text horizontally, like a description, but I'm ending with an ugly thing. I'll post the code below, maybe someone have a clue how to fix this. Thanks !

```
VStack {
  HStack {
                    ForEach(meniu!.ingredients) { men in
                        let ingredient = syncViewModel.fetchByIdIngredients(ingredientId: men.ingredient)
                        if ingredient != nil {
                                Text("\(ingredient?.name ?? "" ), ")
                                    .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                        } else {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
            }

}
```

Comment: skip the `else { EmptyView() }`

Comment: or: with a function combine all ingredients into one string, and present this result string. then you can also show longer combined texts with line breaks.

Comment: @ChrisR same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Ingredient: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

func combinedIngredients(_ array: [Ingredient]) -> String {
    var result = ""
    array.forEach { item in
        result.append("\(item.name), ")
    }
    return result
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let ingredients: [Ingredient] = [
        Ingredient(name: "eggs"),
        Ingredient(name: "sugar"),
        Ingredient(name: "flour"),
        Ingredient(name: "milk"),
        Ingredient(name: "blueberries")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("with ForEach:")
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(ingredients) { ingredient in
                    Text("\(ingredient.name), ")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            
            Divider()
            
            Text("with function:")
            Text(combinedIngredients(ingredients))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would advise against manually concatenating the array to a String. This example also emits the extra `, ` at the end. Better use Swift's built-in `ListFormatter`: `ListFormatter.localizedString(byJoining: array.map { $0.name })`

Comment: fully agreed. tried to keep it simple and educating.

Comment: Using the ForEach method, if your final text will be larger than the screen size, you will have each HStack getting compressed with a weird appearance. Better use the func, turning the array into a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189970/how-to-arrange-the-text-one-after-the-another-with-for-each-in-swiftui/71190041#71190041), check out the answer (use a `func` with `.joined`):

[how to arrange the text one after the another with for each in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189970/how-to-arrange-the-text-one-after-the-another-with-for-each-in-swiftui/71190041#71190041)

```
struct MyRecipe: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe(ingredients: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]))      // Use your code instead of this example array
    }
    
    func recipe(ingredients: [String]) -> String {
        return ingredients.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet it is the same school assignment.